# How to use RegEx to return all results ending with '_thumbnail'?

Tags: php, regex

This pattern will get me all files that begin with a nr and it works perfectly.

```
glob("path_to_dir/^[0-9]*");
```

I want to have a pattern that gets me all files that ends with `_thumbnail` regardless file extension.

eg.

```
1.jpg
1_thumbnail.jpg
2.jpg
2_thumbnail.png
```

will get me

```
1_thumbnail.jpg
2_thumbnail.png
```

I have tried:

```
glob("path_to_dir/(_thumbnail)");
```

but it didnt work.

I would appreciate a little help.

Comment: part of your troubles comes from the fact that you're confusing regular expression patterns with shell glob patterns.  those two are different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Will this do it?

```
glob('path_to_dir/*_thumbnail.*');
```